# Table vs Listview in react-native for data posting

Tags: android, listview, react-native

Hello I'm new in React Native I want to make a attendance system where teacher can select the student and set absent or present. I want to know which is better for data posting since I have to show all student and default will set as present. If any student is absent I will set 'A' this is my logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by ListView you are actually referring to either a FlatList or a SectionList because ListView is actually deprecated. Therefore I'm going to answer your question as `Table vs FlatList`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

As far as I'm aware there isnt actually a Table component in react-native. You can build something equivalent to a table with code like:

```
<View>
    <View> 
        <Text>John</Text>
        <CheckboxButton />
    </View>
    <View> 
        <Text>James</Text>
        <CheckboxButton />
    </View> 
        <Text>Bob</Text>
        <CheckboxButton />
    </View>
</View>
```

**CheckBox isn't core to React-Native you will have to make it yourself**

However! this is clunky and disgusting and really not the best way. That said you could slim it down and move the `<View>` child to its own function like

```
const student = (name) => {
        return (
            </View>
                <Text>{name}</Text>
                <CheckboxButton />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

And then map over each students name in your object. But once again this isnt avoiding the issue, and the issue is that this all needs some form of CSS to keep it clean along with its own method somewhere to map and generate children objects as `student` to the parent object.

---

The alternative is ListView and because this isnt a custom component it is much more organised and cleaner to use. It still has it's weird react-native quirks, specifically around styling but the beauty is that instead of writing multiple methods to build you table you just have to define your object and parse it to ListView.

For Example:

```
const student = name => <View> <Text>{name}</Text> <checkBox /> </View>;

<FlatList
  data={this.props.students}
  renderItem={({item}) => student(items)}
/>
```

Much Much Cleaner and it brings with it a host of styling options. 
Please keep in mind a lot of this is pseudo code, I dont have the capability right now to right correct examples but these are all based off samples I have pulled from my own react-native github repos so they should be close enough to functionality.

All the best and follow up with any questions in the comments.